# Unable to resolve host. No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, networking, connection, wifi, hostname

I'm trying to connect my mobile app with my desktop app, but it's impossible for me.
Both devices are connected to the same wifi and i have the internet permisions on my manifest.

**MANIFEST AFTER application tag**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

[image]

**ERROR**

```
I/System.out: Unable to resolve host "JarsUbuntuComputer": No address associated with hostname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the IPAddress of your Computer in the place of JarsUbuntuComputer and also make sure Port number is same or not

also add this in Manifest in Application tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:allowClearUserData="true"
```

Full Code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: with the IP number works correctly, but i tought that can put the hostname for be sure that is never going to change.

Comment: No its impossible to use hostname, 1) You can use static IP. 2) Generally in desktop your ip will not change if you are connecting with same router or wifi